# How can you force the PropertyGrid to always show the drop-down button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

For enums and other types, once selected the PropertyGrid will show a drop-down button to the right, indicating it can be clicked to be changed. Is it possible to force the PropertyGrid to show this drop-down button all the time, much like it would if they were normal ComboBoxes?

EDIT: To clarify, in the screenshot below the property currently set to Color.Red is selected, so you see the drop-down button, but the property currently set to Color.Blue is not, so you don't see it. I would like to always see the drop-down button.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [PropertyGrid control and drop-down lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593364/propertygrid-control-and-drop-down-lists)

Comment: @LarsTech I don't think that's the same issue.

Comment: I assume then that you intend to force-feed it items at some point?  What you ask is possible, but difficult and messy.  Look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx and related classes.

Comment: If it's not the same issue, then see [Create And Host Custom Designers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx)

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I have found that you cannot force the drop down button to always be visible for every property in the propertygrid. The reason is because the propertygrid only contains 1 dropdown button. So there cannot be multiple drop down buttons visible simultaneoulsy. One solution for properties like enums is to auto click the drop down button when the enum property is selected so that you don't have to select the property line and then click the drop down button yourself (this way it will save one click! :) ). here is a sample code:

```
void propertyGrid1_SelectedGridItemChanged(object sender, SelectedGridItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewSelection != null &&
            e.NewSelection.PropertyDescriptor != null &&
            e.NewSelection.PropertyDescriptor.Converter != null &&
            e.NewSelection.PropertyDescriptor.Converter.GetStandardValuesExclusive() == true)
        {
            System.Reflection.FieldInfo field_gridView = propertyGrid1.GetType().GetField("gridView", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

            object gridView = field_gridView.GetValue(propertyGrid1);                

            System.Reflection.MethodInfo gridView_methode_get_DropDownButton = gridView.GetType().GetMethod("get_DropDownButton", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

            object dropdownbutton = gridView_methode_get_DropDownButton.Invoke(gridView, new object[0]);

            System.Reflection.MethodInfo dropdownbutton_method_OnClick = dropdownbutton.GetType().GetMethod("OnClick", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

            dropdownbutton_method_OnClick.Invoke(dropdownbutton, new object[] { new System.EventArgs() });
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.
Anben

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain all that is going on because I only went deep enough to make it work for one specific instance, but...

Given a property in a class, one that you wish to display as a drop-down:

```
private String _groupHeader = null;
[Category("Display")]
[DisplayName("Group Header")]
[Description("Any adjacent columns sharing this text will be displayed together as a merged header.")]
[DefaultValue("")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(GroupHeaderTypeConverter))]
public String GroupHeader { get { return _groupHeader; } set { _groupHeader = value; } }
```

You then need a `StringConverter`:

```
public class GroupHeaderTypeConverter : StringConverter
{
    private static List<String> groupHeaderList = new List<String>();
    public override Boolean GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context) { return true; }
    public override Boolean GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context) { return false; }
    public override TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context) { return new StandardValuesCollection(groupHeaderList); }
    public static void SetList(List<String> newList) { groupHeaderList = newList; }
}
```

Then, at some point in your code, you have to set the list:

```
private List<String> _groupHeaders = new List<String>();
//add to _groupHeaders
GroupHeaderTypeConverter.SetList(_groupHeaders);
```

In my case, I was loading the `_groupHeaders` list as I was pulling data in from the database.

I'm afraid that's as far as I can go...`TypeDescriptor` is not really my strong suit, but I hope this helps.